# Adding component to blockManager in GrapesJS

Tags: javascript, grapesjs

So I started with grapesjs just the other day, and so far I love it. However, I have hit a road block. In the canvas (#gjs), I have a preset div container:

```
<div id="container"></div>
```

I can create blocks/add them to the blocks section (on the front end which would produce the following structure:

```
    <section class="row">
        <div class="6">Column</div>
        <div class="6">Column</div>
    </section>
```

I can drag the button to the canvas, but I cant seem to drag it into the container (has to be above or below). I then read about components which looked more like what I needed to do. Unfortunately, I have no clue how to actually add the component to the block section or really what to do with it. I might be going about this the wrong way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a component with  "div container"

```
 {
      'id' : '0001',
      'data' : {
             label: `<div>
              <div class="my-label-block">Container</div>
            </div>`,                  
            content:`
                <div id="container"></div>
            `,
            editable: true,
            draggable: true,
            stylable: true,
            category: 'Basics elements',
            selectable: true,
            attributes: {
            class: "fa",
            id: '0001'
            }

      }
    }
```

with options:

```
    editable: true,
    draggable: true,
    stylable: true,
    selectable: true,
```

and then, you will be able to  drag  your "section component into "container component".